# compile single kernel file

Tags: linux-kernel

I am very new to system kernel development. I am using Ubuntu 11.10, and trying to make a new system call. I wonder if there is any way to compile only a single file, which I am working on, instead of compiling the whole kernel.

This is the command I am using to compile the kernel.

`fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=version01 kernel-image kernel-headers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added system calls before. AFAIK, you need to compile the entire kernel because the system call table is static within the kernel.

However, when you hit `make` on the kernel, the kernel building system should workout the dependencies and only compile the files which need to be compiled.

Comment: I was writing a much more long-winded answer that basically came to this conclusion. The only thing I really have to add is that if you don't need to add a new system call, it's much more convenient to write your code as a loadable kernel module. AFAIK kernel modules can't add new system calls.